# ¿Por qué no existe una palabra escrita «hoder» (en vez de la versión con «j-»)?

Tags: etimología, historia, pronunciación, fonología, latín

Se me ocurre que el verbo e interjección malsonante *joder* parece ser una excepción a la regla (o más bien, a la ley) que nos dice que cada palabra (que no sea cultismo) que en latín comienza una *f‑* + VOCAL se ha convertido en *h‑* en castellano moderno. Por ejemplo: *fūmus > humo, furnus > horno, filia > hija*. Véase la discusión más amplia sobre este fenómeno histórico en el artículo de Wikipedia, [“Cambio fonético «f → h» del español”](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cambio_fon%C3%A9tico_%C2%ABf_%E2%86%92_h%C2%BB_del_espa%C3%B1ol).

En latín el verbo que nos dio *joder* era *futuō / futuere*, el mismo verbo que produjo *foder* en portugués, gallego y asturiano. Por eso no veo ninguna razón que explique por qué en castellano tenemos *joder* en vez de *hoder*. No es palabra culta introducida más tarde; debe haber sufrido los mismos cambios fonéticos que vemos en *hacer < facere, hablar < fābulārī, herir < ferire, huir < fugere, hundir < fundere*.

Sí hay unos cuantos casos en que una palabra con *h‑* nos ha dado una con *j‑*, pero no muchos. Un tal ejemplo será el verbo *jalar* que viene del verbo *halar*, y éste del francés *haler*. También existe [*cante jondo*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flamenco#Cante_jondo) en vez de *cante hondo*, pero eso

> no es más que la forma dialectal andaluza de la palabra "hondo", con su característica aspiración de la h proveniente de f inicial.

Pero es muchísimo más común que un verbo en *j‑* venga de uno con *i‑* en latín, como *jactar < iactāre, juzgar < iūdicāre, jugar < iocāre*.

Tengo mis dudas que *futuere > joder* evolucionara así. ¿Existe otra explicación creíble?

Comment: Hay algunas palabras sueltas que he encontrado donde se ha conservado la aspiración: jolgorio y juerga (< folgar < follicāre), jollín (< hollín < fullīgo) — pero esas cosas se pueden encontrar con cualquier cambio de este tipo. Pero yo simplemente tengo que pensar que se debe a que, siendo *joder* incluso antiguamente una palabra para decir copular, que un tal *hoder* habría carecido de la debida fuerza.  Incluso en el occitano, que solía perder la *f* más que el castellano, se ha mantenido la *f*.

Comment: No obstante, es pura especulación mía.  Es una pregunta excelente.

Comment: @guifa Hay una [opinión bastante desarrollada sobre todo esto aquí](http://www.oporteteditores.com/joder/). ¿Y no es solo en el occitano gascón que pasa lo mismo con *f-* > *h-*, y no en los otros dialectos occitanos?

Comment: Lo hicieron por joder. ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[La explicación del artículo que enlazas](http://www.oporteteditores.com/joder/) suena bastante plausible. La palabra *hoder* existió pero claro, era tan vulgar que apenas se tienen registros escritos de la misma... mas alguno hay. El artículo cita como ejemplo el siguiente:

> *De cuánto trabajamos, ¿qué será? "Ellos a hoder, y nosotras a comer" como soldados que están alojados a discrición.*
>
> Francisco Delicado, "La Lozana Andaluza", 1528 (España).

Aunque también se encuentran otros aun más bastos:

> *A coño hodido y a cabeça quebrada, nunca faltan rogadores.*
>
> Hernán Núñez, "Refranes o proverbios en romance", c1549 (España).

Y hasta nuestro amigo Korreas se apuntó:

> *Añaden dos pullas: "kornudo vaias a Rroma", o "kagaxón en tu boka". "Kornudo" por: "hod[ido]".*
>
> Gonzalo Correas, "Vocabulario de refranes y frases proverbiales", 1627 (España).

Y desde luego, aunque la palabra *joder* no entró en los diccionarios de la RAE hasta 1984 (!), sí que hubo otros diccionarios que recogieron *hoder* en su época: aquellos destinados a traducir el español a otros idiomas. Así, tenemos las siguientes traducciones de *hoder* en el NTLLE:

- 1570 CASAS: Hoder. *Fottere*. (Italiano actual: *Possedere sessualmente una donna*.)
- 1607 OUDIN: Hoder, hazerlo à la muger, caualgar, *foutre, cheuaucher, besongner, raccoustrer vne femme, le faire à vne femme*. (Pocas explicaciones necesita.)
- 1609 VITTORI: hodér, hazérlo á la muger, caualgar, *cheuaucher, besongner, accoustrer une femme, le faire à une femme*, caualgare vna donna, ingrauidare vna femina. (¿Ingravidar?)
- 1617 MINSHEU: Hodér. L Futuere, *dict.: de* fundendo semen in genituram.
- 1620 FRANCIOSINI: hoder. [l'azione che si fa nell'atto venereo con vna donna. fottere. (¿Acto venéreo? Qué mal suena eso.)
- 1705 SOBRINO: Hodér, hazerlo à la muger, cavalgar, *Faire l'action charnelle, avoir à faire à une femme.*
- 1706 STEVENS: *Hodér,* to have to do with a Woman, to commit the Act of carnal Copulation.

En todo caso, aunque hay registros son pocos, y la palabra se transmitió por vía oral principalmente. Así que lo más seguro es que sufriera el proceso que dice el artículo: la *h* se fue aspirando cada vez más sin que sufriese corrección alguna, hasta que se empezó a usar con *j*. No puedo resistirme a copiar aquí unos cuantos versos del siguiente texto del siglo XVIII:

> *Y Beatriz, la de las ingles bellas
>
>   y ojos vivos, el pecho alto y carnoso,
>
>   y en él dos tinajillas del Toboso;
>
>   y la resaladísima Antonieta
>
>   de hambrienta vulva y la Catalineta;
>
>   la Matilde y famosa Sacristana
>
>   con el lunar que el muslo la hermosea
>
>   cuando la echan a vuelo cual campana;
>
>   la Poderosa, del joder apriesa,
>
>   con boca de carmín bañada en risa;
>
>   y la Jacinta, del redondo culo,
>
>   la Clara, que al nombrarla, en mi bragueta
>
>   y en mi miembro efundió tanta lujuria
>
>   cuanta de Clara el sucio nombre encierra;
>
>   la Margarita de abultado chocho,
>
>   que hace creer al majadero indiano
>
>   que únicamente guarda para él solo.*
>
> Nicolás Fernández de Moratín, "El arte de putear", c1771-1777 (España).

Este texto seguro que no lo enseñan en las escuelas...