# ¿Cuándo y cómo adquirió la palabra "follar" su acepción sexual?

Tags: etimología, significado, historia, españa, vulgaridades

Creo que hoy día poca gente imagina cosas como:

> 1. tr. p. us. Soplar con el fuelle.
> 2. prnl. Soltar una ventosidad sin ruido.
>
> ---
>
> 1. tr. Formar o componer en hojas algo.
>
> ---
>
> 1. tr. desus. hollar.
> 2. tr. desus. Talar o destruir.

cuando se les habla de la palabra *[follar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=IAeiVzH%7CIAepx9e%7CIAexPVB%7CIAjld1n)*. Es la siguiente acepción la que se nos viene a la cabeza:

> 1. tr. vulg. Practicar el coito. U. t. c. intr.

El caso es que esta acepción entró en el diccionario de la RAE en 1989. Por supuesto, aparecen muchos casos en el CORDE anteriores a esta fecha, con los significados descritos arriba:

> *Mandamos que ninguno non faga figura de cruz nin de santo nin de santa en sepultura nin en tapete nin en manto nin en otra cosa, para poner en lugar do se pueda follar conlos pies; [...].*
>
> Anónimo, "Cortes de Bribiesca de 1387", 1387 (España).
>
> ---
>
> *Semita. femi. dela pri. declina. es la senda que fazen los ombres follando la con los pies continuamente.*
>
> Alfonso de Palencia, "Universal vocabulario en latín y en romance", 1490 (España).
>
> ---
>
> *[...] ni quieras dar lugar a los enemigos de la Santa fe cathólica, que querrán follar los tus santos altares, en que se consagra cada día el tu santo cuerpo [...].*
>
> Anónimo, "Crónica popular del Cid", 1512 (España).
>
> ---
>
> *"Sonar", i "follar", i "sollar", es: soplar las fuelles del herrero; palavras son komo ke manda al mozo.*
>
> Gonzalo Correas, "Vocabulario de refranes y frases proverbiales", 1627 (España).

Sin embargo, entiendo que en algún momento debió de adquirir el significado sexual. Imagino que al principio pasaría como con *[joder](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23922/12637)*, que la expresión se transmitiría de forma oral hasta que alguien se animó a escribirla. La cuestión es: ¿cuándo y cómo adquirió la palabra *follar* el significado actual relativo al coito? ¿Se sabe cuál fue su primera aparición en textos escritos?

Comment: Yo tengo el recuerdo de una explicación que dice que se relaciona con el follaje, lugar que se prestaría (según ellos) para este acto. Voy a ver si encuentro más información.

Comment: Para mí la acción de "soplar con el fuelle" sería la mejor candidata a prestarse como analogía del acto sexual. En [blog 20 minutos](https://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/cual-es-el-origen-de-la-palabra-follar-para-referirse-vulgarmente-al-acto-sexual/) lo explican un poco: "[...]  convirtiéndose en el acto de soplar con el fuelle y que da el significado de ‘resollar’ y/o ‘jadear’. Ese resoplar o **jadeo** realizado con el fuelle (follis) unido al **movimiento que se hace al bombear** fue el que con el tiempo terminó  derivando [...]". Yo añadiría además el **ritmo** al bombear

Comment: "Soltar una ventosidad sin ruido."... wow, jamás se me habría ocurrido este significado para la palabra.

Comment: Follar con el significado de soltar una ventosidad es común hoy día en Colombia (tengo un colega de allí y lo emplea. Obviamente la primera vez que lo oí, tuve que preguntarle en plan «pero tú...¿qué!»

Comment: @Diego: Apoyo tu teoría: me he encontrado con gente que, hablando en catalán, usaron la palabra *manxar* ("manxa" = fuelle) para referirse a tener el acto sexual. No he encontrado un diccionario de catalán que recoja este uso de "manxar", aunque sí que sale en este diccionario de valenciano http://www.avl.gva.es/lexicval/?paraula=Manxar

Comment: @Octania ¡curioso! Porque el [Diccionari d'Alcover Moll](http://dcvb.iecat.net/) no recoge la acepción, pese a ser conocido como el _más laxo_ en cuanto a aceptar términos. Ah, yo también lo he oído en catalán con relativa frecuencia.

Comment: Yo huelo, nosotros olemos. Es probable que venga de una deformación de oler, como los perros que se huelen antes del coito. La hache podría haber sido reemplazada por una efe, como es común en Hernando y Fernando, facer y hacer, de holer a foler, y de allí a follar. Es probable también que el cambio de infinitivo se deba a un uso concentrado del verbo conjugado en las personas del singular, dado que el acto de oler suele ser más singular que colectivo. Es una asociación libre la mía.

Answer (score 2):

El DLE nos muestra lo siguiente:

> **folgar**
>
> 1. intr. desus. holgar.
> 2. intr. desus. Tener ayuntamiento carnal.

El mapa de diccionarios lo empieza a incluir con el ayuntamiento carnal en 1884 y follar con el significado buscado a partir de 1992 (aunque la RAE casi siempre va unos años atrasada con el idioma, pero esa es otra historia), así que follar sería una adaptación, lo que traslada la duda hacia *folgar*.

Folgar ya aparece por lo menos unos 180 años antes de lo que indica el mapa de diccionarios con la segunda acepción, en un libro de un tal Miguel de Cervantes... Al iniciar el capítulo XIX de la primera parte de *[El Ingenioso hidalgo Don Quijote de la Mancha](https://es.wikisource.org/wiki/Don_Quijote,_Primera_Parte:_Cap%C3%ADtulo_XIX)*, dice Sancho Panza:

> -Paréceme, señor mío, que todas estas desventuras que estos días nos han sucedido, sin duda alguna han sido pena del pecado cometido por vuestra merced contra la orden de su caballería, no habiendo cumplido el juramento que hizo de no comer pan a manteles ni con la reina folgar, con todo aquello que a esto se sigue(...)

Ahora es cuestión de confirmar la adaptación de la palabra y la existencia de fuentes previas (que es lo más seguro)

Answer (score 2):

A través del CORDE he encontrado una única referencia, de **1874** [**Don Juan Notorio: burdel en cinco actos y 2000 escándalos**](http://www.cervantesvirtual.com/obra-visor/don-juan-notorio-burdel-en-cinco-actos-y-2000-escandalos--0/html/ff86058c-82b1-11df-acc7-002185ce6064_2.html#I_0_)

(Acto I, Escena II, versos 108 y ss):

> Aquí está Don Juan Tenorio,
>   para quien quiera joder.
>   Los romanos caprichosos,
>   los muchachos licenciosos,
>   yo gallardo... por mi fe,
>   apuesto que no dejé
>   más de dos culos mohosos.
>   Salí de Roma por fin,
>   como os podéis figurar,
>   con un disfraz harto ruin,
>   y a lomos de un mal rocín,
>   pues que me querían **follar**.
>   ...
>   A quien quise me tiré,
>   a quien quiso la metí,
>   y nunca consideré
>   que pudo joderme a mí
>   aquél a quien yo **follé**.

lo que indica que ya en ese año (1874) se conocía y usaba "follar" en la acepción sexual.