# ¿Por qué la RAE recomendaba usar "u" como conjunción en vez de "o" ante palabras que empezaran por "d"?

Tags: gramática, historia, ortografía, conjunciones

Hojeando el *Diccionario de Autoridades* veo las siguientes definiciones:

> **ITERAR**. Repetir lo que se ha hecho ù dicho varias veces. (Tomo G-M, de 1734.)
>   **REITERAR**. Volver à executar ò repetir alguna cosa. (Tomo O-R, de 1737.)

Me resulta curioso que en un libro escrito en 1734 se usara *ù* como conjunción a pesar de que la siguiente palabra no provocara cacofonía, mientras que en 1737 ya se usara *ò*. Veo en todo caso que en el tomo de 1734 sí se usa *ò* en otros casos: "lo mismo que triángulo equilátero, ò cuyos tres lados son iguales". Y lo mismo en el tomo de 1737 con *ù*: "se llama también el clavo ù hierro redondo, con que se juega al herrón".

Pregunta pues: ¿qué norma siguió la RAE en su *Diccionario de Autoridades* con respecto al uso de *o/u*? ¿Cuándo se escribía una y cuándo otra? ¿Cómo cambió esta norma y cuándo se estableció en la que tenemos actualmente?

Tengo el siguiente punto de partida: la definición de *u* en el citado diccionario:

> Sirve muchas veces de partícula disiuntiva, especialmente quando la dicción acaba en *o*, ò la siguiente empieza con ella, para evitar la cacophonia, ò quando la dicción siguiente empieza con *d*, para quitar la mal sonancia.

Esto explica bastante los usos de *ù* en los textos mencionados, dado que en un caso la palabra siguiente empieza por *d*, y en otro la anterior acaba en *o*, pero introduce una nueva cuestión: ¿qué malsonancia se provocaba al juntar *o* con una palabra que empezara por *d*?

Comment: Que raro... Nunca había visto esta antigua 'regla' antes. Juan de Valdés dice nada sobre la *'d'* en su [*Diálogo de la lengua*](http://www.cervantesvirtual.com/obra-visor/dialogo-de-la-lengua--0/html/fede437e-82b1-11df-acc7-002185ce6064_2.html#I_0_) cuando habla sobre el uso de la *u/o* como conjunción disyuntiva.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La web Enclave RAE dispone de un blog, y precisamente la última entrada (a día de hoy), *[Por el arco del triunfo](https://enclave.rae.es/blog/por-el-arco-del-triunfo)*, aborda este tema en los siguientes términos:

> Otro nutrido grupo de eufemismos es el de los empleados para evitar la palabra *jod…* Entre otros, el español cuenta con ***[joroba](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MXFryB0%7CMXGJTWI)***, ***[jopé](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MWkSFZo)*** y ***[jo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MUqKUQQ%7CMUqOdQ6)***, ***[jolín](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MVzRpRb%7CMW6Wl04)***, ***[jolines](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MW6s3bb)*** (sobre su origen, véase el discurso de ingreso en la RAE de Federico Corriente), o incluso *jopelines* [...].
>
> El afán de evitar cualquier secuencia similar a *jod…* puede explicar por qué en algunas ediciones del diccionario académico del siglo XVIII se recomendaba sustituir la conjunción *o* por *u* delante de una palabra con *d-* inicial [...].

Y cita el siguiente ejemplo:

> *El Theatro de la vida humana, las Polyantheas, y otros muchos libros, donde la erudición está acinada y dispuesta con orden alphabético, **o** apuntada con copiosos índices, son fuentes públicas de donde pueden beber, no solo los hombres, mas también las bestias. Qualquier assumpto que se emprehenda, se puede llevar arrastrando a cada passo a un lugar común, **u de** política, **u de** moralidad, **u de** humanidad, **u de** historia.*
>
> Benito Jerónimo Feijoo, "Teatro crítico universal".

Se ve que el grupo "o de" podía sonar demasiado similar a *hoder*, [registrada por diccionarios desde 1570](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23925/12637) (aunque no en los de la RAE, demasiado vulgar) con el sentido actual que conocemos. Esta malsonancia es la que la RAE quería evitar a toda costa, al parecer. Se ve que por entonces la primera consonante no se aspiraba tanto como para provocar el sonido *j* que usamos hoy día para hablar del mismo concepto, y la malsonancia era más obvia.

La regla de usar *u* en vez de *o* como partícula disyuntiva ante palabras que empezaran por *d-* se mostró en el diccionario de la RAE hasta su versión de 1803 inclusive.

Curiosamente, la *Gramática* de la RAE tenía su propia opinión al respecto, dado que ya en su primera edición de 1771 decía:

> La *ú* se usa en lugar de *ó* quando la palabra siguiente empieza por *o*, por la misma que la *é* por la *i*, como: siete *ú* ocho, por siete *ó* ocho.

Básicamente la misma regla que observamos hoy día.

Answer (score 0):

Solo podría encontrar estas referencias con respecto a este tema, que dicen que sí había una razón de *«alguna aspereza de sonido»*, pero no explican bien lo que fue:

> Donde hallares *U* por disyuntiva en lugar de *O*, no pienses que es descuido ni error de impresión, ni cuidado presuntuoso de introducir novedades, sino **por templar alguna aspereza de sonido, causada de** otras *oes*, u de **alguna *d***, cuanto más que la lengua latina, grave y calificada madre de la nuestra, contiene cuatro partículas para significar división, y cada una dellas tiene *u*.
>
> Así que parece cosa llegada a buena razón suplir con su riqueza este vacío, adquiriendo por honesto camino variedad de lenguaje, sin incurrir en impropiedad ni licencia. Y nadie la tome de juzgar esta advertencia por menuda, porque, aun no siendo más que una letra, sin ser como es dicción, no se debía añadir ni quitar con menos requisitos.
>
> - [*La seiscientas apotegmas y otras obras en verso*](https://archive.org/details/laseiscientasapo00rufo), Juan Rufo Gutiérrez

> En Granada, Calderón y otros de nuestros clásicos se pone u por o antes de la preposición d; **el motivo o no subsiste hoy, o se desestima.**
>
> - [*Gramática de la lengua castellana destinada al uso de los americanos*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=lE2lufx0YUkC&pg=PA391&dq="u"+"o"+"d"+"disyuntiva")

Hay [ejemplos](https://www.staff.ncl.ac.uk/i.e.mackenzie/cons.htm) de "od" `[o.d]` > "ud" `[u.ð]` en la evolución de castellano:

- *iŭdaeum* [ʝoˈdεo] > Old Sp. *judio* [ʒuˈðio] > [ʃuˈðio] > [xuˈðio] *judío*

Puede ser que tenga algo que ver con esto?

---

---

**Más información:**

<sup>En las notas a pie de página de muchas colecciones de poemas antiguos, hacen mención de esto, pero lamentablemente sin más explicaciones:</sup>

> <sup>*u deificando:* en Lope y en otros autores coetáneos es usual utilizar la *u* como conjunción disyuntiva ante *d*; ver por ejemplo, *El perseguido, Parte I,* vol. I, acto I, p. 289, v. 390: «Decidme cómo u de quien»; *El primero Benavides, Parte II,* vol. II, acto III, p. 976, v. 3302: «con diez u doce caballos». *Cfr.* Rufo, «Al lector», en *La seiscientas apotegmas* p. 13: «donde hallares *u*...»</sup>
>
> <sup>• [*La hermosura de Angélica: poema*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=j39lAAAAMAAJ&q=%22en+Lope+y+en+otros+autores+coet%C3%A1neos+es+usual+utilizar+la+u+como+conjunci%C3%B3n+disyuntiva+ante+d%22), Lope de Vega, ‎Marcella Trambaioli (p308)</sup>

> <sup>Todavía el Diccionario de autoridades señala que u «sirve... malsonancia». • [*El jardín de Falerina*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=QKQqAQAAMAAJ&q="u"+"o"+"d"+"disyuntiva") (p111)</sup>

> <sup>**u:** «Sirve... malsonancia» (Aut.). • [*El Eneas de la Virgen y primer rey de Navarra*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=JaEqAQAAIAAJ&q=%22u%22+%22o%22+%22d%22+%22disyuntiva%22&dq=%22u%22+%22o%22+%22d%22+%22disyuntiva%22), (p114)</sup>

> <sup>**u:** o. [En el Diccionario de Autoridades se explica que u «sirve... malsonancia». En la práctica podía tomarse en cuenta la d final precedente, como se hacía con la o, y como sucede en el presente ejemplo. Pero a veces se usaba u sin intervención de la o ni de la d. • [*Noches Lúgubres*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=35ZdAAAAMAAJ&q=%22u%22+%22o%22+%22d%22+%22disyuntiva%22&dq=%22u%22+%22o%22+%22d%22+%22disyuntiva%22), (p208)</sup>

> <sup>• [*Propalladia, and other works of Bartolomé de Torres Naharro: Notes*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=JDlfAAAAMAAJ&dq="u"+"d"+"o"+"aspereza+de+sonido")</sup>