# ¿Cómo se convirtió el "xocoatl" del náhuatl en "chocolate"? ¿Es esta su etimología real?

Tags: etimología, historia, comida, náhuatl

El DLE nos dice que

> [**chocolate**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8wy33KW)
>
> ```
> Etimología discutida; cf. náhuatl xocoatl, de xoco 'amargo' y atl 'agua'.
> ```
>
> 1. m. Pasta hecha con cacao y azúcar molidos, a la que generalmente se añade canela o vainilla.
> 2. m. Bebida que se hace de chocolate desleído y cocido en agua o en leche.
> 3. m. coloq. hachís.

Como vemos, define la etimología como discutida. Sea como fuere, suponiendo que efectivamente *chocolate* viene de *xocoatl*, ¿cuál fue el recorrido fonológico para pasar de una a otra? ¿Por qué no decimos *chocoate* por ejemplo? En particular, me interesa saber cómo y cuándo apareció la *l* intercalada (lo de por qué dudo que se sepa).

Mirando en el NTLLE me encuentro con entradas de 1609 que ya hablan de *chocolate*. Teniendo en cuenta que se "descubrió" a ojos españoles en el siglo XVI con la llegada de Colón a América, no observo demasiado margen de tiempo para ir evolucionando el vocablo desde su supuesta raíz náhuatl al vocablo "definitivo" en castellano.

Comment: no existio evolucion del vocablo por que los españoles mal tradujeron todo lo que aprendian de los indigenas para poderlas pronunciar facilmente

Comment: @aparente por qué esa tilde?

Comment: @fedorqui - las palabras del náhuatl que terminan en -atl son así, p. ej. Quetzalcóatl y náhuatl.  (Una fuente: http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:133341/FULLTEXT01)

Comment: @aparente001 estás mencionando palabras que pertenecen ya al castellano y, por tanto, se rigen por las reglas de acentuación de este idioma. Pero precisamente _xocoatl_ no, y ya el DLE y todas las otras referencias que puedas encontrar lo muestran sin tilde en su idioma original (náhuatl). Es como si compararas una referencia al _gâteau_ francés y lo acentuaras según las reglas españolas sin que hayamos adaptado esta palabra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Según los diccionarios etimológicos ingleses, falta una *l* ahí en medio. Te cito primero el [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chocolate):

> Spanish, from Nahuatl *chocolātl*, probably an alteration of eastern Nahuatl dialect *chikolātl*, from *chikolli* hook (probably used to refer to the beater used to mix chocolate with water) + *ātl* water, liquid

Y a continuación la web de [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/chocolate):

> c. 1600, from Mexican Spanish *chocolate*, from Nahuatl (Aztecan) *chocola-tl*, "chocolate," and/or *cacahua-tl* "chocolate, chocolate bean." With *a-tl* "water." In the first form, the first element might be related to *xocalia* "to make something bitter or sour" [Karttunen]. Made with cold water by the Aztecs, with hot water by the Conquistadors, and the European forms of the word might have been influenced by Mayan *chocol* "hot." Brought to Spain by 1520, from there it spread to the rest of Europe.

Como ves, las etimologías difieren ligeramente pero ambas coinciden en colocar una *l* intermedia (*chocolātl*, *chocola-tl*) que explicaría la pronunciación actual. Otra explicación la da la web italiana [etimo.it](http://www.etimo.it/?term=cioccolatte) (traduzco):

> los etimologistas españoles se decantan por CHOCO *cacao* y LATUL *agua*

Aunque también menciona la palabra XOCOATL como posible origen. De hecho esta explicación de *choco* (cacao) y *latl* (agua) también aparece en el DLE de 1914, tras decir que viene del mejicano *chocolatl*.

Por su parte, el *Breve diccionario etimológico* de Corominas dice:

> h. 1580. Palabra de origen azteca, pero de formación incierta. Como las noticias más antiguas acerca de la preparación de este brebaje son de que los antiguos mejicanos lo hacían con semilla de ceiba (*póchotl*) y de cacao (*cacauatl*), quizá provenga de *pocho-cacaua-atl* 'bebida de cacao y ceiba', abreviado por los españoles en **chocauatl* (en la forma actual pudo haber influjo fonético de otros brebajes mejicanos, como *poçolatl* 'bebida de maíz cocido', *pinolatl* 'bebida de pinole', *chilatl* 'bebida de chile').

Comment: ¡Es decir que falta una _l_ ahí en medio en el original náhuatl!

Comment: @fedorqui a eso apuntan los documentos consultados, en todo caso estoy intentando buscar más referencias.

Comment: Oh, veo que en [Historia del chocolate en España#la denominación del nuevo alimento](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historia_del_chocolate_en_Espa%C3%B1a#La_denominaci%C3%B3n_del_nuevo_alimento) hay bastante chicha.

Comment: Aunque hay algo que chirría: allí mencionan _En todas esas obras aparece siempre la palabra cacahuatl ('agua de cacao'), una denominación muy razonable para una bebida elaborada con agua y cacao_, cosa curiosa porque es [_cacahuete_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6TormOr) la palabra cuyo origen es _cacáhuatl_.

Comment: @fedorqui efectivamente. La palabra _cacauatl_ la menciona Corominas como la usada para "cacao", al igual que la web de Etymonline. Corominas dice para _cacahuete_ que viene de _tlalcacáuatl_, 'cacao de la tierra'.

Comment: @fedorqui Además, ten en cuenta que en español (al menos en castellano antiguo) la combinación *tl* no era habitual (de hecho la edición actual del DLE trae aprox. 80 palabras con esa combinación y más del 70 % surge en América). Similar ocurre con vocablos como Aguacate (si son muy sensibles, no busquen su origen), Cacahuate, Chicle, Tomate o Zapote (los más usados...)

Comment: @VeAqui caramba, tremenda etimología la del aguacate :)

Answer (score 2):

You're quite right to note that the proposed etymology in the DLE requires a few phonetic leaps not seen in other Nahuatl words loaned to Spanish. Not just in the position of the *l*, but the *x → ch* (which usually remained [*x/j* or became *s*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23602/18348)).

The Nahuatl word for chocolate drink is *cacahuatl*, "cacao water". *Cacao* itself, pronounced by the Olmecs as *kakawa*, dates to 1000 BC or earlier.<sup>1</sup>

The word *chocolātl* does not appear in any early Nahuatl sources, and indeed only first appears in Spanish accounts from the late 16th century, shortly after the Spanish had already adopted the term *cacahuatl* (which survives today in Spanish in the form *cacahuete*, referring to the fruit/tree).

Coe & Coe suggest that the novel word was coined by the Spanish themselves (citing Mexican philologist Ignacio Davila Garibi and anthropologist Miguel León-Portilla) due to the unfortunate connotations of ***caca**huatl* to their ears:

> It is hard to believe that the Spaniards were not thoroughly uncomfortable with a noun beginning with caca to describe a thick, dark brown drink which they had begun to appreciate. They desperately needed some other word.
> ...
> Spaniards had coined the word by taking the Maya word *chocol* ["hot"] and then replacing the Maya term for water, *haa*, with the Aztec one, *atl*.
>
> - [*The True History of Chocolate*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=39zZAAAAMAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=caca), Sophie Dobzhansky Coe, Michael D. Coe (p118-119)

For similar displacements, see:

- [ósculo → beso](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/26384/18348) (ósculo ~ os culo (cular/culear))
- [o de → u de](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/26371/18348) (o de ~ hode' ~ hoder ~ joder)

---

<sup>1. [*Cacao use and the San Lorenzo Olmec*](http://www.pnas.org/content/108/21/8595), Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences</sup>