# ¿Por qué dejó de usarse "ósculo" como "beso" y se convirtió en un cultismo?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, historia, sustantivos

Hoy día tenemos dos palabras para hablar del *beso*, aunque una de ellas se usa solamente como cultismo:

> **[beso](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5PQqqPX)**
>
> ```
> Del lat. basium, voz de or. celta.
> ```
>
> 1. m. Acción y efecto de [besar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5PMFiht) ["Tocar u oprimir con un movimiento de labios a alguien o algo como expresión de amor, deseo o reverencia, o como saludo"].

> **[ósculo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RHVQ2pj)**
>
> ```
> Del lat. oscŭlum.
> ```
>
> 1. m. cult. Beso de respeto o afecto.

Estas dos palabras aparecen registradas en textos del siglo XV, que explican sus diferencias. Por ejemplo:

> *Osculor. es verbo comun. osculor te: & osculor a te. Dende viene osculum: beso que demuestra prenda de caridad: & señal de amor. y es osculum beso que se da alos fijos. & paz alos amigos. & basium ala muger. & suauio ala mançeba. por que representa suaue & halagueña deletaçion: nombra se de suauidad: como osculum de boca.*
>
> Alfonso de Palencia, "Universal vocabulario en latín y en romance", 1490 (España).

Es decir, el beso que se da a los hijos, amigos, que denota caridad y amor, ese era *osculum*, y se reservaba *basium* para los besos que se dan a la mujer y que denotaban amor... pero de otro tipo. De los que implican deleite, como dice de los que se dan a la manceba (que en ese caso eran *suavium*).

Esta distinción la recogía Nebrija en su diccionario de 1495 también, de la siguiente forma:

> Beso onesto. osculum.i.
>   Beso de enamorado. basium. suauium.ij.

Otros diccionarios de la época también recogían la diferencia. Sin embargo, Covarrubias en 1611 ya recogía *besar* de la siguiente forma:

> BESAR. Lat. osculor.aris. Beso Lat. osculum.

Y tras una introducción pasa a explicar qué es el beso, especificando que "es señal de paz", "también el beso es señal de confederación", tipos de besos solemnes, que no hay nada ilícito en besar el marido a la mujer pues las escrituras manifiestan lo contrario, etc.

El Diccionario de Autoridades mantiene esta línea, y es el primero que recoge la palabra "ósculo", afirmando simplemente que significa "lo mismo que beso". Es decir, parece que desde el siglo XV al menos ya se venía usando principalmente la palabra *beso* (esto lo confirman los resultados de buscar "[beso*](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?MfcISAPICommand=buscar&tradQuery=1&destino=1&texto=beso*&autor=&titulo=&ano1=0&ano2=1500&medio=1000&pais=1000&tema=1000)" y "[oscul* o óscul*](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?MfcISAPICommand=buscar&tradQuery=1&destino=1&texto=oscul*%20o%20%F3scul*&autor=&titulo=&ano1=0&ano2=1500&medio=1000&pais=1000&tema=1000)" en el CORDE para textos anteriores a 1500, siendo el primero un orden de magnitud superior al segundo en cuando a número de casos). Pero ¿por qué? ¿Qué pasó para que se eliminara esa distinción y nos quedáramos solo con una palabra de uso mayoritario para cualquier tipo de beso?

Teorías al respecto:

- Había casos en los que era difícil distinguir la intención del beso y no se sabía si había que usar *beso* u *ósculo* y, por comodidad, se eliminó esa diferenciación.
- La palabra *beso* tenía su correspondiente verbo *besar*, usado ya en el siglo XIII, que favoreció el uso de *beso*, mientras que *ósculo* no conservó su verbo.
- La palabra *osculum* significaba también *boca pequeña* según algunos textos, como el propio diccionario de Nebrija, lo que podría confundir su uso.
- La palabra *osculum* era ya un cultismo en latín, y como tal no se propagó por el latín vulgar con la misma fuerza que *basium*.

¿Cuál de todas sería la razón principal, si es que alguna es correcta?

Comment: Sobre el verbo correspondiente a ósculo, en *La venganza de Don Mendo" tienes: “...  tutéame y si te place, **osculeame** en las dos mejillas”

Comment: @Rotten curioso. En el NTLLE no aparece ni "oscular" ni "osculear", aunque sí hay 5 fichas en el Fichero General que reflejan el uso de "oscular" en algunos (pocos) textos.

Comment: A riesgo de sonar tonto pregunto, ¿no es posible pensar que la mera rima o resonancia de la palabra *ósculo* y su hipotético verbo correspondiente hayan disuadido a los hablantes de seguir empleándola?

Comment: @pablodf76 si te refieres a que pronunciar "beso" es más fácil que pronunciar "ósculo", como hipótesis no es nada tonta.

Comment: @Charlie: Me parece que pablodf76 se refiere a que ósculo rima con "trasero" y osculear con "sodomizar"... y sería muy fácil que se produzcan malos entendidos... ¡¿Que le estabas haciendo qué a mi hija?! Así empiezan las guerras... :-D

Comment: @Wences eso podría generar otra pregunta: ¿se usaba la palabra "culo" allá por el siglo XIII? Porque hablamos de que en el siglo XV ya solo se usaba "beso", luego "ósculo" debió dejar de usarse antes...

Comment: @pablodf76 y Wences, encontrado texto del siglo XII que habla sobre penas que se aplican a determinadas conductas, entre ellas: "Totus homo qui uerbo malo dixerit 'fodido in culo', o 'cornudo', o 'gafo', per istos". Pues igual es verdad que "ósculo" sencillamente tenía una mala resonancia...

Comment: Yo coincido con @pablodf76 y no me parece tonto pensar que los hablantes la dejaron de usar por su rima con _culo_. De verdad que la palabra no suena bonito ni inspira lo mismo que _beso_ para los que no estamos acostumbrados a oírla y menos a usarla.

Comment: Comparte la misma etimología con el osculum de las esponjas marinas: un pequeño agujero, boca y anus en el mismo tiempo.

Comment: @Charlie Más que una mala resonancia tenía mala fama: véase `osculum infame`

Comment: @Potter-Pirbright [Osculum infame](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osculum_infame)

Comment: @enxaneta suena plausible, aunque no deja de ser curioso que hoy día tenemos la expresión [beso negro](https://dle.rae.es/?id=5PQqqPX#FtJBpYp) para expresar lo mismo y no por ello dejamos de usar la palabra _beso_. Los tiempos han cambiado... :-D

Answer (score 2):

La idea de que había una diferencia en la especie o intención de beso disignado por las distintas palabras latinas (*osculum, basium, s[u]avium*) no se apoya en [los ejemplos de sus usos](http://vunex.blogspot.com/2006/09/kiss-me-kiss-me-kiss-me-for-latin.html), en los que cada una se emplea en cualquier contexto.<sup>1</sup>

Dicho esto, *osculum* es abrumadoramente la palabra más popular en la literatura latina. Esto, además del hecho que sus cognados en muchas otras lenguas románicas también se consideran 'literarios' o 'anticuados' o 'poéticos', y en cambio la palabra habitual es [un cognado de *beso*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/basio#Descendants), e.g:

- `lat` ōsculum | bāsium

  - `pt` óculo | beijo
  - `es` ósculo | beso
  - `it` osculo | bacio

me hace creer que su caída en desuso debe preceder al desarrollo de castellano, en el habla latín vulgar:

> ... the growing rift in the spoken and written languages of Carolingian Europe, as noted by the 813 Council of Tours, may have unconsciously finalised the distinction between *osculum* and *savium* (written Latin) and *basium* (spoken vernacular).
>
> - [*Kiss me, kiss me, kiss me: for the Latin lover*](http://vunex.blogspot.com/2006/09/kiss-me-kiss-me-kiss-me-for-latin.html), [Conrad H. Roth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Archives/Humanities/2008_July_24#Who_is_Conrad_H._Roth?)

y que los escasos usos medievales de *ósculo* en castellano son 'literarios', evocando el estilo de la poesía latina.

---

**Notas:**

1. > <sup>The most notable fact here is the overwhelming dominance of osculum, used for every kind of kiss, both in prose and poetry: superstitious (Vergil), mock-friendly (Jerome), chastely tender (Lucan), romantic (Ovid), erotic (Lucretius), official (Tacitus). [...]</sup>
   > <sup>The distinction between these words cannot be primarily one of meaning (whether social or anatomical), but must rather be one of register.</sup>

Comment: Related: the Spanish word [*buz*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=6MVG2Ct) "Beso de reconocimiento y reverencia."